# Question from Putnam '08: Given $F_n(x)$, find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!F_n(1)}{\ln(n)}$

Tags: limits, contest-math, proof-verification

> **Problem Statement:** Let $F_0(x) = \ln(x)$.  For $n\ge0$ and $x\gt0$, let $F_{n+1}(x) = \int_0^xF_n(t)dt$.  Evaluate
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!F_n(1)}{\ln(n)}$$
>   Source: Putnam 2008, Problem B2.

---

**My solution:**

First, show by induction that:
$$F_n(x) = \frac{x^n}{n!}\left(\ln(x) - H_n\right)$$
...where $H_n$ is the $n$th harmonic number.
(Induction proof omitted because it is trivial, and doesn't relate to my question)

Then, the limit becomes:
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!F_n(1)}{\ln(n)} &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{\ln(n)}\frac{1^n}{n!}\left(\ln(1) - H_n\right) \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left(\ln(1) - H_n\right)}{\ln(n)}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-H_n}{\ln(n)}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-H_n}{\ln(n)} \tag{1}\\
&= -\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(n) + \gamma}{\ln(n)} \tag{2}\\
&\overset{\text{L'H}}{=} -\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}} \tag{3}\\
&= -1 \tag{4}\\
\end{align}$$

(where $\gamma$ is Euler's Constant)

---

**My Questions**

1. For Putnam-style grading, do I have to prove the limit exists by definition (e.g. $\epsilon-\delta$ proof)?
2. Do I have to show that I can apply limit rules (e.g. L'Hopital's from $(2)$ to $(3)$) to limits of discrete variables?
3. In between lines $(1)$ and $(2)$, I made a jump based on the definition that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(H_n - \ln(n)) = \gamma$  So, as $n$ becomes large, $H_n$ is approximately $\ln(n) + \gamma$.  I am most uneasy about this step, as it feels like a "back of the paper" sort of substitution and not a rigorous one.  Is this a justified step?

And, of course, I'd be open to suggestions/comments on the style of my solution and general rigor, but the above three points are the main ones to which I'm looking for answers.

Comment: As for your question (3), you can easily make that rigorous by just saying that $H_n = \ln n + \gamma + o(1)$ - in fact, even the approximation $H_n = \ln n + O(1)$ is enough.  You don't even need L'Hopital's; just say that it's $\frac{\ln n+O(1)}{\ln n} = 1+O(\frac1{\ln n})$

Comment: Thanks! How do I know that the difference is $o(1)$ or even $O(1)$? Is this by definition or something?  (I'm a little fuzzy on certain properties of series/approximations)

Comment: Oh.  I forgot to use the @StevenStadnicki notifier.  (oops)

Comment: That's a standard enough result on the Harmonic series that I think you're safe using it - that $H_n=\ln n+\gamma+o(1)$ is a little bit deep, but that $H_n = \ln n+O(1)$ is IMHO safely in 'common knowledge' (and relatively easy to prove too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like your perception of this problem may be backwards: to my mind, the induction to prove the form of $F_n(x)$ is the 'meat' of the problem, and once you've got that result it's the rest of the problem that's trivial.  To answer your specific questions, though: you shouldn't need an epsilon-delta proof for limits on a Putnam; once you have an explicit form for $F_n$ (and note that the first integral is improper so a little justification may help there), you can manipulate the limit quite a bit — as long as you don't do anything improper, you should be fine.

In this case, if you didn't know the form of the Harmonic series explicitly (and I would personally take $H_n = \ln n+O(1)$ as well-enough established that it didn't need independent justification, but I wouldn't fault someone for feeling otherwise) then you can use Riemann estimates for $\int_1^n \frac1x dx$ to bound it: just break it up as $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\int_i^{i+1}\frac1xdx\right)$ and note that the integral in parentheses is bounded between $\frac1{i+1}$ and $\frac1i$.  Summing, this gives $\ln n\leq H_n\leq \ln n+1$, and that's more than enough to give the result: since $F_n(1) = -\frac{H_n}{n!}$ then $-\frac{\ln n+1}{n!}\leq F_n(1)\leq -\frac{\ln n}{n!}$ and so $-\left(1+\frac1{\ln n}\right)\leq \frac{n!F_n(1)}{\ln n}\leq -1$; the squeeze here is trivial, and you don't need L'Hopital's rule at all.

In general, rigor in contest problems is to be encouraged, but it should also be the last thing you work on; for an exam like the Putnams where you (almost certainly) won't be able to complete all the problems, putting effort into a new problem is IMHO more likely to bear fruit (and points) than the last few drops of rigor on a problem you've already gotten a result for.

Comment: Wow.  I really like the squeeze argument.  :) and, I do agree - the biggest part of the problem was the induction, but, as the most I've done with limits was in the first month of Calc 1, the induction was the easy part for me.